# ADB Failure: Error: must either specify a package size or an APK file

Tags: terminal, installation, adb

I'm trying to install an apk via adb on a mac. It's not my mac, but they have adb and it sees the rooted phone correctly (verified using `adb devices`, so I know adb works, too).

However, when I try to install the app:

```
adb install [app_name].apk
```

I get the following message:

```
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install [app_name].apk: Error: must either specify a package size or an APK file
```

I *know* the file is an apk, it is a good version (I've installed it successfully on other phones using other computers), it downloaded completely, and I am in the same directory as the file. It is also spelled correctly (I even tab-completed to be sure).

I can't seem to fine any real google results on this error, however. Does anyone know what might be causing it? How to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So the issue here appears to have been a file-format error. In this case, the apk didn't download all the way to the computer, even though it looked normal. Therefore, it wasn't registering as a true apk. By deleting the file and redownloading it to the computer, I was able to successfully install the app using `adb`.